# Passing whole model to controller from view via link

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to pass an entire model to the controller. Right now it passes nothing and I don't know why. The Model is partially filled in when it get's to this page, so it should atleast have some info in it.

The problem: When I click on the button on the view, the model is not passed to the controller. Not even the filled in parts!

View (that contains a model that is partially filled in)

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Winkelmand";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout3.cshtml";
}
@model IntroSport.Models.Bestel

<br />

<br />
@if (Model.winkelmand.facturen != null)
{
    <table style=" width:auto; height:auto; border-style:solid; border-color:black;">
    <tr><th>Artikelnummer</th><th>Merk</th><th>Naam</th><th>Prijs</th><th>Aantal</th></tr>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.winkelmand.facturen.Count; i++)
    { 
        <tr>
        <td>@Model.winkelmand.facturen[i].product.ProductID</td>
        <td>@Model.winkelmand.facturen[i].product.Merk</td>
        <td>@Model.winkelmand.facturen[i].product.Naam</td>
        <td>€@Model.winkelmand.facturen[i].product.Prijs</td>
        <td >@Model.winkelmand.facturen[i].Aantal</td>
        </tr>
    }
    </table>
}
<br />
<hr />
<b>Totaal: </b>€ @Model.winkelmand.Totale_prijs

<a href="@Url.Action("Klantoverzicht", "Winkelmand", Model)">Bestel!</a>
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult KlantOverzicht(Bestel bestel)
    {
        return View(bestel);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You would not be able to simply provide the whole model into the `@Url.Action` and have it create the link with each of the fields in your model.

You essentially will need to create the link "by hand"!

From the view that you have, it appears the user is not changing any information, and most likely, you pulled the information you are displaying from a database, so if you do create the link that passes in the model, the information will match the data in your database.

My suggestion would be that instead of posting an unchanged model to the server, you simply pass in the Id of the object into your view and have the view retrieve the object from the database.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Klantoverzicht", "Winkelmand", new { id = Model.Id })">Bestel!</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You're absolutely right about how I created this code and the code behind this. Thing is; the Bestel model consists out of two other models (Model A and Model B, let's say). Model A is retrievable from the database but model B not, seeing model B is yet to be filled in after the user pressed on the link.

Answer (score 0):

You can send `Model` to controller with `<form>`.

Or send all properties by link and in action collect them to a new model.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Klantoverzicht", "Winkelmand", 
         new { 
               pId = Model.ProductID,
               mark = Model.Merk,
               name = Model.Naam,
               price = Model.Prijs,
               number = Model.Aantal,
             })">Bestel!</a>
```

In action:

```
public ActionResult KlantOverzicht(int pId, string mrk, string nam, double price, int number    )
{
  Bestel model = new Bestel();
  model.ProductID = pId;
  model.Merk = mark;
  model.Naam = name;
  model.Prijs = price;
  model.Aantal = number;
}
```